# Adjusting the table width with the page width and defining cell width at the same time

Tags: tables, adjustbox, cell, column-width

I am writing a text in LaTeX and I need to insert a big table in it. As it is quite wide and I wanted to adjust it to the page width, I used the `\begin{adjustbox}` command. However, I have a problem with it (to illustrate it better, I am attaching an image down below).

The thing is that I have a first cell, at the left, which comes from the combination of several cells, and as I have a lot of text in it, I want to have the text written in several lines. For that, I thought of using the `|p{3cm}|` command, so that the cell would maintain that width and the text would be written in several lines. This is the result I want, which comes from Excel (there are more columns at the right side of what I'm showing)

[image: This is the result I want]

The thing is that both commands, `\begin{adjustbox}` and defining the cell width, seem to be incompatible, and although the table adjusts to the page width, the first column doesn't adjust to those 3cm and the text is written in one single line. Do you know how could I manage to adjust the table width to the page witdh and, in addition, define the width of one column so that the text is written in more than one line?

OK, I'll try to express myself in English. I am using the `tabulary` environment this way:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|P{0.3\linewidth}|L|L|L|L|L|L|}
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
```

I have also tried defining:

```
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|P{3cm}|L|L|L|L|L|L|}
```

And the table keeps taking more than the page space. I don't know if I am doing something wrong, or if I have to add something to my code.

Anyway, thank you so much for your answer. I am not used to make tables in LaTeX, and when I have done one, it was quite easier than this one I have to add to my TFG...

I am uploading another image of how I want my table to look like[image]

As u can see in the left column, I need cells ton be smaller so that the text is written in several lines and the cell is less wide. I dont know if there is a problem with the `\multicolumn` I am using in the table head or if there's any other problem

Im showing here the code Im using

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[total={170mm,257mm}, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\parindent=15mm

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel} %"españoliza" LaTeX: separación de palabras, formato de fecha, etc
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabulary}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering

\begin{tabulary}{1.0\textwidth}{|L|L|L|L|L|L|L|}
        \toprule
{\multirow{2}{=}{\centering Paper}} & {\multirow{2}{=}{\centering Organismo}} & {\multirow{2}{=}{\centering \Proteína}} &{\multirow{2}{=}{\centering Gen}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Homólogo Anabaena sp. PCC7120} \\
        
        \cmidrule{5-7}       &       &       &       & Gen & Anotación & Identidad (\%)}\\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\end{table}
```

I tried just showing which I consider important for the table, sorry if I exceeded

The this is that in the column "Paper" I write the reference of the articles, and the cell I use to write it comes from the combination os several cells, so I would need it to be written in several lines so that it doesnt occupies too much space.

I have been thinking about all this problem and I think thay what I need is the next:

- First of all I need to define de width of each column, so that the whole table fits in the line width
- Second, I need to reduce de size of the font. Just reducing the width of the cells, I would have some cells in which appear more than one line and where I need one single line. E. g.:

```
 &       & Polysaccharide biosynthesis/export protein; GumB/KpsD (Sistema Wzx/Wzy) & \textit{sll1581 (gumB)} & \textit{all4388} & SLBB domain-containing protein} & 39,18 \\
```

In this row, there is too much text and I need and smaller size of font so that it all fits in one line. You can see it in the previous image I added, in the column "proteína" there are too much text, and I need an smaller font to make it fit in one line.

Comment: With the `tabulary` package you can set the maximun width of the table and then you can use also L,C, R or J columns that adapt to that space as needed  (e.g.: in `\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LRJclrp{3cm}} ... \end{tabulary}` only the c, l and r columns  cannot have line breaks). Similarly, with `tabularx` you can  fix the width of the table and  use  special columns (X) that equitably use the available space.

Comment: Fran, is your native language Spanish? Maybe I could ask u better that way, because I am spanish

Comment: Yo también,  pero aquí solo debemos usar el inglés, aunque nos salga un poco chusco.

Comment: Hay que escribir en inglés en este sitio porque es importante que todos los usuarios pueden entender. Para bien or para mal, inglés es la lingua de la comunidad y solo un poco de los expertos pueden leer y escribir español.

Answer (score 2):

Your table si to wide that can be (nicely) fit on portrait oriented page. Also at landscape oriented page it doesn't fit well without reducing font size to `\footnotesize`.

By use of the `tabularray` table (is to my opinion) coloring cells and rows as well composing multirow cell simpler. However in comparison to `tabulary` it doesn't automatic determine column width. You need to prescribe them.

A possible MWE is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,
            marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}
\parindent=15mm

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel} %"españoliza" LaTeX: separación de palabras, formato de fecha, etc
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{vline{1,2,5,Z} = {1pt},
             vline{3,4,6,7} = {solid},
             colspec = {X[1,l,m] X[1,c,m] X[3,l] c c 
                        X[2.5,l] Q[c, si={table-format=2.2,
                                        output-decimal-marker={,}}]},
             colsep  = 3pt,
            row{odd} = {bg=cyan!30},
            row{1,2} = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries, c, bg=cyan!50}
            }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Paper
    &\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Organismo 
        &\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Proteína 
            &\SetCell[r=2]{c}    Gen 
                &\SetCell[c=3]{c}    Homólogo Anabaena sp. PCC7120   
                    &   &                       \\
    \cmidrule{5-7}       
    &   &   &   & Gen 
                    & Anotación 
                        & {{{Iden. (\%)}}}  \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=10]{c, bg=cyan!50}   Parnasa at all., 2019
    &\SetCell[r=6]{c}   Syechococcus elongatus PCC 7942
        &   & * & * & * & *                     \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   & synpcc 7942\_1134
                &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   & synpcc 7942\_1134   
                & air7014  
                    &   & 57.7                  \\
    &   &   &   &   &   & 73.99                 \\
    &\SetCell{bg=white} Anaboena sp. PCC 7120
        &   
            &   &   &   & *                     \\
    &\SetCell[r=3]{c, bg=cyan!30}   Microcytis aeruginisa PCC 7806
        &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &                       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]